# AWS Kinesis sequence numbers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I have a kinesis consumer which is running from past 3 days..but still it didn't read the producer data

Producer put the data at sequence number -> 49593554362799306497476712297116585830001273292214763522

and consumer is reading at -> 49592407930728695436502186699740292765095159714163982338

Can anyone help me in understanding these sequence numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your consumer started reading at LATEST position after records have been already produced. Try changing it to TRIM_HORIZON. Check AWS docs for details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html